# Should you give a large amount of charity to single entity or split it up across many entities?

Tags: tzedakah-charity

The situation comes up a lot.
You're praying the morning prayers in synagogue and it's erev shabbos/yom tov; the collectors flood the synagogue. Should you give a bigger amount to fewer collectors or try to split up what you're willing to give to accommodate them all?